# Docker compose com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud

I tried to implement an **example** of **Spring Boot Microservice** examples.
I have a problem in **docker-compose** file.

**Eureka server** and **api gateways** throws an **issue** defined below while there is no issue in config server.

Here is the issue : `com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server`

Here is the **code snippets** **for config server**.

```
configserver:
    image: configserver
    container_name: configServer
    build:
      context: ./configserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://localhost:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
    ports:
      - "9191:9191"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "configserver"
```

Here is the **code snippets** for **eureka server**

```
eurekaserver:
    image: eurekaserver
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    build:
      context: ./discoveryserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://localhost:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "eurekaserver"
```

Here is the **code snippets** for **api gateway server**.

```
gatewayserver:
    image: gatewayserver
    ports:
      - "8600:8600"
    build:
      context: ./api-gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PROFILE: "default"
      SERVER_PORT: "8600"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://localhost:9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      eurekaserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "gateway"
```

Here is all docker-compose.yml : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are no longer running on localhost.

So change:

```
EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
```

To corresponding service container name, take Eureka server for instance:

```
EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
```

See [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2442#issuecomment-344338485).